# dojo how to get Portlet is hidden on Closable Property?

Tags: dojo

I'm working on a project using Dojo. I am using Gridcontainer and Portlet. I have a problem. I set the value to true in the properties of the Closable Portlet. And when i click the close button will be hidden Portlet. I want to get the information of the hidden Portlet. Please help me!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What information of the hidden portlet? The portlet is still accessible from the `dijit/registry` module, for example:

```js
registry.byId("myGrid").addChild(new Portlet({
    id: "portlet1",
    title: "My portlet",
    content: "My portlet content",
    closable: true
}), 0, 1);

registry.byId("myBtn").on("click", function() {
     console.log(registry.byId("portlet1"));   
});
```

Which should return the portlet widget object, containing all the information it has.
Example: http://jsfiddle.net/pajpne39/

Comment: thanks!! but can i tell you another question?!! When many Portlet, i need to close the Portlet that have information. information that any property value.for example, i've been writing random console.log(registry.byId("portlet1").close)-> true